# com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type using a RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am facing this problem since , i read this post [database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38864428/database-databaseexception-cant-convert-object-of-type-java-lang-string-to-type)  but still am getting the same error, where am wrong please . I need your help am new in Firebase.

This is my `MainActivity.java` class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button but;
    private DatabaseReference mRef;
    private MyAdapter adapter;
    public RecyclerView recyclerView;

    public List<ModelClass> doctors;
    public Context c;
    private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;

    public DatabaseReference mMovieRef ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        doctors = new ArrayList<ModelClass>();

        recyclerView =(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);

        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRef =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Doctors");

        mRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                LoadData(dataSnapshot);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                LoadData(dataSnapshot);
            }

            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { }
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) { }
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { }
        });
    }

    public void LoadData (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
        for(DataSnapshot ds :dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            System.out.println(ds.getValue());
            ModelClass doc =ds.getValue(ModelClass.class);

           doctors.add(doc);

           adapter = new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, doctors);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my `Adapter` class

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {
  protected   Context c;
    List<ModelClass> doctors;
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

   StorageReference url =storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://askdoctor-546bf.appspot.com/");

    private List<ModelClass> itemList = null;

    public MyAdapter(Context c, List<ModelClass> doctors) {
        this.c = c;
        this.doctors = doctors;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_activity,parent,false);
        MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(v);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final  ModelClass feedItems = itemList.get(position);

        holder.name.setText(doctors.get(position).getDoctorsName());
        holder.email_txt.setText(doctors.get(position).getEmail());
      // PicassoClient.downloadImage(c,doctors.get(position).getUrl(),holder.img);
        //Download image using picasso library
        Picasso.with(c).load(url+ feedItems.getPhoto())
                .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).
                resize(120, 50)
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(holder.img);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return doctors.size();
    }
}
```

This is my `model` class

```
public class ModelClass {
    private String DoctorsName;
    private String Email;
    private String Phone;
    private String Photo;

    public ModelClass() {

        // empty default constructor, necessary for Firebase to be able to deserialize  posts
    }

    public String getDoctorsName() {
        return DoctorsName;
    }

    public void setDoctorsName(String doctorsName) {
        DoctorsName = doctorsName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return Email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        Email = email;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return Phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        Phone = phone;
    }

    public String getPhoto() {
        return Photo;
    }

    public void setPhoto(String photo) {
        Photo = photo;
    }
}
```

This is my Firebase [database Console picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3p9i.png).

Comment: Please include the complete, minimal code + JSON (as text, no screenshot)  that reproduces the problem in your question. Also include the complete stack trace as that includes crucial information on what is going wrong.

Comment: where did the error occur? look at the logcat / Android monitor after the error occurs to find out which line it is

Comment: Any particular reason you are not using the firebase recyclerview adapter? Check this out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2J6spwAVP0M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are trying to access the child of doctors one and two, try this code

```
         public void LoadData (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)

        {            

        System.out.println(ds.getValue());

        ModelClass doc =ds.getValue(ModelClass.class);

       doctors.add(doc);

       adapter = new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, doctors);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: i think we are near the answer , i tried that, and it brought another error check this out  `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference` , but it printed what;s in the database `09-20 21:26:24.138 1988-1988/oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase I/System.out: {Photo=namasuba.jpg, DoctorsName=Lutaaya, Phone=0704594180, Email=hux@gmail.com}` and  `I/System.out: {Photo=namasuba.jpg, DoctorsName=Huzaifah, Phone=0706081457, Email=luts@gmail.com}` in the logcat @Jay