# Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem after I add another table to my firebase database. it gives me following error:

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type ...

here is my code, which works fine if I have database like this:
[image]

and code:

Main activity code:

```
rvOrder = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvOrders);
rvOrder.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
firebaseHelper=new FirebaseHelper(databaseReference);

myAdapter=new MyAdapter(this,firebaseHelper.retrieve());
rvOrder.setAdapter(myAdapter);

databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        rvOrder.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

Firebase helper code:

```
public class FirebaseHelper {

DatabaseReference databaseReference ;
Boolean saved = null;
ArrayList<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();

public FirebaseHelper(DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
    this.databaseReference = databaseReference;
}

public Boolean save(Order order) {
    if (order == null) {
        saved = false;
    } else {
        try {
            databaseReference.child("Orders").push().setValue(order);
            saved = true;

        } catch (DatabaseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            saved = false;
        }
    }
    return saved;
}

private void fetchData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    orders.clear();

    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

        System.out.println(ds.getValue(Order.class));
        Order order = ds.getValue(Order.class);
        orders.add(order);
    }
}

public ArrayList<Order> retrieve() {
    databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            fetchData(dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            fetchData(dataSnapshot);

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    return orders;
}
```

If I change my code to this (which I saw in this question [link to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38864428/database-databaseexception-cant-convert-object-of-type-java-lang-string-to-typ) ):

in Main activity:

```
databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

to

```
databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Orders");
```

and in firebasehelper:

```
for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    System.out.println(ds.getValue(Order.class));
    Order order = ds.getValue(Order.class);
    orders.add(order);
}
```

to

```
System.out.println(dataSnapshot.getValue(Order.class));
Order order = dataSnapshot.getValue(Order.class);
orders.add(order);
```

then I am able to add another tables to database but I just get only the last item from the Orders table.

I want to add  many tables with multiple items into the database and also I want to get all items from the "Orders" table.

Can anybody suggest me anything?

Comment: There's a bit much code in your question. Can you reduce it to the [minimal complete code that reproduces the error](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first code snippet you read from the root of the database. Since you're trying to read orders, you should read from `/Orders` instead:

```
databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
firebaseHelper=new FirebaseHelper(databaseReference);

//myAdapter=new MyAdapter(this,firebaseHelper.retrieve());
//rvOrder.setAdapter(myAdapter);

databaseReference.child("Orders").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
```

Now in your `onDataChange` you can read the orders by looping over them. Since you already do precisely that in `FirebaseHelper.fetchData`, you can call that method:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    firebaseHelper.fetchData(dataSnapshot);
}
```

Now all that is left is to wire up the data from `firebaseHelper.orders` to an adapter and the view:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    firebaseHelper.fetchData(dataSnapshot);
    myAdapter=new MyAdapter(this,firebaseHelper.orders);
    rvOrder.setAdapter(myAdapter);
}
```

This last step will require that you make `FirebaseHelper.orders` public, and probably some of the variables must be `final`.

Comment: Now it works. There is still a red line says `E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout` but I'll find out the reason later on. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to update this method accordingly:

```
public Boolean save(Order order) {
    if (order == null) {
        saved = false;
    } else {
        try {
            databaseReference.child("Orders").push().setValue(order);
            saved = true;

        } catch (DatabaseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            saved = false;
        }
    }
    return saved;
}
```

Try to change:

```
databaseReference.child("Orders").push().setValue(order);
```

To:

```
databaseReference.child("Orders").child(order.getId).setValue(order);
```

Also, to retreive all Orders keep using the enhanced loop:

```
    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

    System.out.println(ds.getValue(Order.class));
    Order order = ds.getValue(Order.class);
    orders.add(order);
}
```

Comment: I don't have function     getId()    in Order class. What should I return if I define that function, order name? 
If I use that    for()    loop I get the same error, unfortunately.